# Eclipse Mars: install new software does not work

Tags: ubuntu, eclipse, plugins

I've installed Eclipse Mars, and need to install the SVN plugin. When I click `menu: Help > Install new software`, I select All Available Sites, and normally something happens in the main window, items appearing or activity indicating that it's downloading information.

Now I don't see anything happening. I can click the "select all" button, and then 2116 items are selected. Nothing appears in the window. At first I thought this was a problem with the Dark Theme I used, but changing that to the Classic theme didn't help. Restarting didn't help.

**What can I do to install plugins in Eclipse Mars on Ubuntu 14.04?**

Comment: Similar thing I'm facing with Mars-v4.5.2 on Ubuntu(16.04LTS x64).

Comment: @Sparkot - See the link below!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that Eclipse mars on Ubuntu 16.04 runs so slowly it appears to be hung up.  Solution can be found on the [Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761604/eclipse-not-working-in-16-04) SO site...

Comment: Thanks! I've changed to Netbeans since, but prefer to go back.